# Newsstand installation leaves shadow "installing" icon

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, testflight

On a iOS5 Newsstand application we are developing we are having a strange behavior which I wonder you know what this is about.
The application is being downloaded and installed from TestFlightApp correctly into iOS "desktop" upon finishing the installation it moves to Newsstand (which is expected behavior as this is a Newsstand app) and disappears from the location it was being downloaded. If I swipe to another section of home screen, and go back, I see again the app icon on the desktop with "Installing" message and bar at 100%. The application works perfectly on Newsstand rack, but the shadow "Installing" icon on the desktop stays there until the phone is restarted. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am seeing the same thing

Comment: Also can you tell me if your app uses Core Data? And if so is there any chance you were adding a new version to your data model in this update?

Comment: I think it is a minor bug of iOS itself.

Comment: a year has passed, iOS6 is here, but the bug stays.. Have you ever found a solution? Maybe, there are some specific plist keys that should be used for Newsstand OTA apps, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into this same problem and believe I found the source.

On an existing project, I had changed the iOS Bundle ID from the default `com.yourcompany.ClientName` to `com.ClientDomain.ClientName`.

I published a new IPA and dropped it into our "adhoc" web directory for distribution. Meanwhile, in the `.plist` file, the `key` bundle-identifier `/key` and string `com.yourcompany.ClientName` `/string` was still there, so it no longer matched.

Once I updated the "yourcompany" part to `ClientDomain`, the shadow icon problem was resolved.

Hope that helps someone in the future!